# How can virtualenv create different python environments?

Tags: python, virtualenv

My server has 3 `virtualenv` scripts:

```
$ ls -lt virtual*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4 Nov 22 06:19 virtualbox -> VBox
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 55 Aug 14 19:34 virtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 55 Aug 14 19:34 virtualenv2
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 55 Aug 14 19:34 virtualenv3
$ cat virtualenv
#!/usr/bin/python3
import virtualenv
virtualenv.main()
$ cat virtualenv2
#!/usr/bin/python2
import virtualenv
virtualenv.main()
$ cat virtualenv3
#!/usr/bin/python3
import virtualenv
virtualenv.main()
```

I know `virtualenv2` is used to create `Python 2` environment while `virtualenv3` is for `Python 3`. But what confuses me is why just modify the `/usr/bin/python2` to `/usr/bin/python3` in shebang line can achieve the effect that create different environments? What is the magic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two pieces of "magic".

1) The shebang line informs the kernel of the correct interpreter to use. When you invoke `virtualenv2`, the kernel expands that to `/usr/bin/python2 virtualenv2`. Similarly, when you invoke `vitualenv3`, the kernel expands that to `/usr/bin/python3 virtualenv3`.

2) The `virtualenv.main()` creates a virtual environment based upon the currently running interpreter. For example, if `virtualenv.main()` is invoked by `/usr/bin/python3`, then it creates a virtual environment based upon `/usr/bin/python3`.

Hopefully you can see that these two "magic" items, taken together, perform the intended action.